# Removing the single quote from a list of ids

Tags: python, api

I need to append/format a URL with a list of ids for an API call.

However, when I put the list at the end of the API:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/lookup.json?user_id=%s'%a
```

I just get an empty string as a response.

I have tried turning the list into a string and removing the square brackets, doing:

```
a = str(followers['ids'])[1:-1]
```

but I still get the same problem. I'm assuming that it's being caused by the single quote at the start.

I have tried removing the apostrophe from the string doing:

```
a.replace("'", "")
```

and now I have run out of ideas.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Can you show what you want the resulting url to be, and what you're actually getting?

Comment: You do not have the problem you think you have, or you have written this very unclearly. Your problem is not that the stray ' is in your code. Your problem is that you are trying to do string substitution without providing any string. You need to supply the API with a user ID, or comma separated list of same. "%s%a" isn't a valid ID.

Comment: [`str.replace`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) does not modify the string, it *returns* the new string -- you have to say `a = a.replace("'", "")` to do the replacement.  Just saying `a.replace("'", "")` is a no-op.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> *I have tried removing the apostrophe from the string doing ...*

You can remove apostrophe from a string using `s = s.replace("'", "")`. [`.replace()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) returns a new string but does not change the orginal string so you'll to store the returned string.

```
>>> string = "he's a jolly good fellow"
>>> string = string.replace("'", "") 
>>> string
'hes a jolly good fellow'
```

**But I don't think that's not your problem.**

The [ids need to be comma separated](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/lookup#api-param-lookup_user_ids), so you'll probably want to use a [`.join()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to create the string from your list of ids. Example:

```
>>> ids = ["1", "23", "123"]
>>> ",".join(ids)
'1,23,123'
```

In your case, assuming `followers['ids']` contain a list of id as strings, you can generate your URL using:

```
ids = ",".join(followers['ids'])  # generate string of ids (comma separated)
url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/lookup.json?user_id=%s" % ids
```

If `followers['ids']` is a list of integers instead of string, then there's a little more work to do since `.join()` works only with a sequence of strings. Here's one way to convert those integers to string on the fly (using a [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/)):

```
ids = ",".join(str(id) for id in followers['ids'])
```