# Is it possible to remove all single quotes from a list of strings in python?

Tags: python

I have 3 lists, yearlist, monthlist and daylist. I'm trying to combine all 3 and add strings between them.

```
for i in range(0,j):
    singledate = 'datetime(year=' + yearlist[i] + ', month=' + monthlist[i] + ', day=' + daylist[i] + ')'
    datelist.append(singledate)
print singledate
print datelist
```

This prints singledate as `datetime(year=2009, month=01, day=15)`, but datelist as `['datetime(year=2009, month=02, day=14)', 'datetime(year=2009, month=01, day=15)']`

Is it possible to remove all " ' " in datelist? Thanks

Comment: There are no `'` in the datelist.

Comment: Please refer to the similar question here
http://stackoverflow.com/a/12604750/1541888

Comment: `for i in range(0,j)` is the same as `for i in range(j)`, just a heads up.

Comment: Thanks sasubillis, I seen that but that question is only talking about removing the characters from the string before adding it to the list. Is it possible to add them so they remain in the list format, ['string1', 'string2'] but without the quotation marks, i.e. [string1 string2]? Thanks

Comment: I think it's very important for you to understand why it doesn't make sense to say "remove the single quotes from a list of strings"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for `datetime`, You don't want to use string, Try something like this,

```
In [12]: import datetime
In [13]: datelist = [datetime.datetime(yearlist[i],monthlist[i],daylist[i]) for i in range(0,j)]
```

**Result**

```
[datetime.datetime(2009, 1, 14, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2009, 2, 15, 0, 0)]
```

Comment: Thank you! I guess I asked a different question to what I really wanted but this was it! I had to use (int(yearlist[i]), int(mothlist[i]), int(daylist[i])) but worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

This is expected here. As your singledate is a string. and datelist is list. 
so when you print the same it will get printed the format as shown above.

You can join the list into a string and get the output as you asked like this. I am doing a join on your datelist and print the same.

```
for i in range(0,j):
    singledate = 'datetime(year=' + yearlist[i] + ', month=' + monthlist[i] + ', day=' + daylist[i] + ')'
    datelist.append(singledate)
print singledate
print " ".join(datelist)
```

Answer (score 0):

The quotes are displayed because you are directly printing a list containing strings. This is the normal and desired behavior.

```
>>> alist = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> print(alist)
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

If you want to print the same content without quotes, you have to format it by yourself:

```
>>> print('[{}]'.format(', '.join(alist)))
[a, b, c]
```